# OWIN Auth HTTPContext NULL on BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

Trying to create a base controller that is inherited across my whole site as it loads the navigation bar dynamically based on user role.

The issue is that it seems to always load and try to get user role even if the owin has not yet loaded and user is not yet logged in.

Below is the BaseController named LayoutController

```
 [Authorize]
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
    public List<NavigationMenuModel> MainLayoutViewModel { get; set; }

    public LayoutController()
    {
        this.MainLayoutViewModel = new List<NavigationMenuModel>();
        using (var context = new OperationalDataContext())
        {
     //The BELOW LINE IS ISSUE
            var username = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.Name;
            var pages = context.GET_PAGES_BY_USERNAME(username);
            var pagesTop = pages.Where(x => x.Parent == null);
            foreach (var page in pagesTop)
            {
                var tmpNM = new NavigationMenuModel();
                tmpNM.DisplayName = page.Name;
                tmpNM.RelativeUrl = page.RelativeUrl;
                var children = pages.Where(x => x.Parent != null && x.Parent.Equals(page.Name) && x.Site.Equals("PRODUCT"));
                List<NavigationMenuModel> tmpChildren = new List<NavigationMenuModel>();
                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    var tmpC = new NavigationMenuModel();
                    tmpC.DisplayName = child.Name;
                    tmpC.RelativeUrl = child.RelativeUrl;
                    var children1 = pages.Where(x => x.Parent != null && x.Parent.Equals(child.Name) && x.Site.Equals("PRODUCT"));
                    List<NavigationMenuModel> tmpChildren1 = new List<NavigationMenuModel>();
                    foreach (var child1 in children)
                    {
                        var tmpC1 = new NavigationMenuModel();
                        tmpC1.DisplayName = child1.Name;
                        tmpC1.RelativeUrl = child1.RelativeUrl;
                        tmpChildren1.Add(tmpC1);
                    }
                    tmpC.Children = tmpChildren1;
                }
                tmpNM.Children = tmpChildren;
                this.MainLayoutViewModel.Add(tmpNM);
            }
        }
        this.ViewBag["MainLayoutViewModel"] = this.MainLayoutViewModel;
    }
}
```

Then there is the dashboardController (homepage)

```
 public class DashboardController : LayoutController
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

We have a simple cookie based login that is allow anayomous

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
{
    IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("login")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
 }
}
```

In the startup.css

```
public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
        });
    }
```

The issues seems to be that it doesn't redirect to login before trying to go to layout.

The AccountController doesn't reference LayoutController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you're doing what you're doing in the constructor of the controller.

The `Authorize` attribute checks for every method if the user is logged in and - if not - redirects him/her to the login page. The contructor code is executed on creation of the Controller - way before any method is called.

Override `OnActionExecuting` on your `LayoutController` and move the constructors code there. I'm not quite sure if the `Authorize` attribute intercepts the calls to the controllers methods **before** `OnActionExecuting` is executed, but I would give it a try.

By the way: `AllowAnonymous` is used to reverse a controllers `Authorize` attribute for a single method. So if your `AccountController` hasn't set this attribute, there is no use in `AllowAnonymous`. But this is a bit off topic.

Hope it helps.